# I can't figure out what's wrong with the two lines of code that are different colors

Tags: azure, kubernetes, visual-studio-code

I have no idea what's wrong with this code and why it's not the same color as all the other text. I can't run anything until it's fixed.

[image: VS code image of problem]

I have tried retyping it, adjusted the indenting, asking my teacher, nothing is working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post screenshots when you have plain text available; it makes troubleshooting much more difficult.

Comment: If your teacher couldn't find this, that may be an issue. Experienced programmers find issues like this all the time. (Took me about 20 seconds to spot it)

Answer (score 3):

end of line 28 you have a `”` instead of a `"`. So yaml thinks line 29 is a continuation of the string on line 28. Replace the `”` with `"` on line 28